# List the keys (key name and versions) based on keyring using java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-kms

I'm using a java client to retreive available keyrings from google KMS based on https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/samples/kms-quickstart#kms_quickstart-java

below gcould command will list the available beys and versions for a specific keyRing

```
gcloud kms keys list --keyring keyring --location location
```

but I'm able to find any documentation about the java client to retrieve key names and versions from the keyring. is there any option available in gogle KMS java client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Cloud KMS Client Library](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-kms/latest/index.html)

The example in the page you referenced includes [`listKeyRings`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-kms/latest/com/google/cloud/kms/v1/KeyManagementServiceClient.html#listKeyRings-com.google.cloud.kms.v1.LocationName-).

To enumerate a specific keyring's (crypto) keys, I think (!?) you can use [`listCryptoKeys`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-kms/latest/com/google/cloud/kms/v1/KeyManagementServiceClient.html#listCryptoKeys-com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyRingName-) to (also) get pages (!) of [`ListCryptoKeysPagedResponse`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-kms/latest/com/google/cloud/kms/v1/KeyManagementServiceClient.ListCryptoKeysPagedResponse.html) that you should be able to `iterateAll()`.

> **NOTE** These examples don't (!?) fetch subsequent pages of results; you will need to do this.

Unless you're familiar with the auto-generated javadocs, navigating these APIs can be gnarly.

A few things to know:

1. Google (almost without exception) does an excellent job with its SDKs. If an API method exists, you can be very confident that the functionality is present in a Google SDK of your choosing; you just need to find it!
2. [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is an excellent tool for understanding Google's APIs (it used to do a better job referencing SDKs too). In this case, Cloud KMS [`keyRings.list`](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings/list) and [`keyRings.cryptoKeys.list`](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys/list) not only document the method functionality but summarize the request|response objects.
3. Any (!) `gcloud` command can be tweaked with `--log-http` to show which underlying REST API calls are being made, i.e. `gcloud kms keys list --keyring=${KEYRING} --location=${LOCATION} --log-http` should (!) reference back to [`keyRings.cryptoKeys.list`](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys/list)